# Laravel -6 Email with Raw Data

Tags: api, email, pdf, attachment, laravel-6

Using Email Body and Attachment at a time

My Code is:

```
 Mail::send( [],array(), function ($message) use ($fromName,$fromEmail,$receiptEmailSubject,$receiptEmailData,$emilId,$pdf){
            $message->to($emilId)
                    ->from($fromEmail,$fromName)
                    ->subject($receiptEmailSubject)
                    ->setBody($receiptEmailData, 'text/html')
                    ->attachData($pdf->output(), 'receipt.pdf',['mime' => 'application/pdf']);
        });
```

But unable to use "setBody" and "attachData" as like. (If removed any one email sending works Properly. Need to remove "setBody" OR "attachData")

How to use "setBody" and "attachData" together ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `setBody` and `attachData` together in Laravel